# How to perform a recursive loop?

Tags: angularjs, recursion

I have the following code which gets the data from a third party API, which is at *example.com*:

```
$scope.buttonClick = function () {
    $http.get('https://example.com').
        success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log(data.pagination.next);

            for (var key in data.applicants) {
                if (data.applicants[key].email == "xxx@example.org") {
                    console.log('found');
                    console.log(data.XXX[key].id);
            }
        }
    }).
    error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        // log error
    });
}
```

Now it contains pagination which is in `data.pagination.next`

If data which is coming from third party can be more then 1 page, I want to perform this operation recursively to check if email id matches, then it return the id which is in if condition, Above code work well if there is one page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should separate the code for checking from the code that's retrieving, and wrap the latter in a function. Then with a few if/elses just do pretty much the same.

```
$scope.buttonClick = retrieveData;

function retrieveData( pageId ) {
    var params = { pageId: pageId || 1 };
    $http.get('https://zzz.com', params).
        success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            var applicantFound = searchApplicantMail( data );
            if( ! applicantFound && data.pagination.next ) {
                return retrieveData( data.paginantion.nextPage );
            }
            doSomethingWith( applicantFound );
        }).
        error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            // log error
        });
}

function searchApplicantMail( data ) {
    for (var key in data.applicants) {
        if ( ! data.applicants.hasOwnProperty(key) ) {
            continue;
        }
        if (data.applicants[key].email == "xxx@xxx.com") {
            return data.applicants[key];

        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: many thanks for the answer giorgio but I'm getting the following error : 
"$http is undefined"

Comment: That's actually quite weird, as `the $http service is a core Angular service` ([doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)). Did you forget to make it available in your controller, like `angular.module('my.module').controller('MyController', ['$http', function($http) { // mycode }]);`?

Comment: btw those functions should be a member of your controller, otherwhise `$http` will indeed not be available most probably.

Comment: ohhhh sorry abt that I forgotton :X that was my mistake that work perfectly :) thanks mate